How to make Vimeo video cover full screen without whitespace in React.js?
I am working with a next.js project using react-player to embed a Vimeo video. My goal is to make the video cover the entire screen without any whitespace, similar to a background video. However, the video maintains letterboxing (black bars) and doesn’t fully cover the container. I’ve tried to find ways to make the Vimeo video cover the full screen without whitespace, but I haven’t been able to get the desired result. It works perfectly for standard video file formats, but I’m struggling with Vimeo.
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/vimeo';

const FullscreenVimeoPlayer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="video-container">
      <ReactPlayer
        url="https://vimeo.com/your-video-url"
        className="react-player"
        playing={true}
        loop={true}
        muted={true}
        width="100vw"
        height="100vh"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FullscreenVimeoPlayer;


CSS:
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.react-player iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}


The container fills the screen, but the video itself doesn't fully cover the area—there are black bars around the video on certain screen sizes.
Expected behavior:
I expect the Vimeo video to stretch and cover the full width and height of the screen, without any black bars or whitespace, similar to how object-fit: cover works with images.
Actual behavior:
Currently, the video maintains its aspect ratio and leaves black bars (letterboxing) around it, especially on wider or taller screens, instead of stretching to fit the full container.
Question:
How can I make the Vimeo video fill the entire screen without any black bars, similar to a background video, using react-player or another method in React?

This works with a video element, because the browser knows what aspect ratio the video has. You are just object-fitting the iframe here, but that doesn't influence the content inside the iframe. And if the actual aspect ratio your iframe gets from this, is different from the aspect ratio of the video, you will get black bars - either on either side, or on the top & bottom.

AFAIK, there is no other way to solve this, than to "do the math", and then size & position the iframe accordingly. Let's, for simplicity's sake, assume the video had an aspect ratio of 1:1, and your viewport had a size of 1000px * 500px, so 2:1. Then you would need to make your iframe 1000px high and wide, and position it "centered" (with overflow cut off), so that 25% of the iframe stick out at the top, and 25% at the bottom. And vice versa, if the viewport aspect ratio was 1:2 instead.

@C3roe Thank you so much for your reply and guidance! Yes, I achieved this by doing maths, just as you explained. Thanks!
